# JavaScript code error: image doesn't show

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am working on a WordPress site and I have placed the following code in my JavaScript file:

```
function blockAdblockUser() {
    if ($('.sideAd').height() == 0) {
        "<a href='http://google.com' target='_blank'><img src='image.png' /></a>";
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    blockAdblockUser();
});
```

...and I put the following code in my html...

```
<section class="sideAd">
    <!-- google ad script here -->
</section>
```

Basically, I am trying to get the alternate image to show up if the user is blocking ads with AdBlock. However, with AdBlock turned on, the image doesn't show. I am thinking there is something wrong with how I wrote this line `"<a href='http://google.com' target='_blank'><img src='image.png' /></a>";` I am still a novice when it comes to JavaScript.

Can anybody see where the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take the string that you've made and actually set it as the inner html. You can fix it by changing the inner line to:

```
$('.sideAd').html("<a href='http://google.com' target='_blank'><img src='image.png' /></a>");
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
function blockAdblockUser() {
    if ($('.sideAd').html() == "") {
        $('.sideAd').append("<a href='http://google.com' target='_blank'><img src='image.png' /></a>");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function blockAdblockUser() {
    if ($('.sideAd').contents().length) {
        $('.sideAd').append("<a href='http://google.com' target='_blank'><img src='image.png' /></a>");
    }
}
```